# Jquery - shift data to the left when when div is emptied

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Hello I have 4 div layers that empty on clicked. I am trying to set an action for the data to shift to the left when layer is clicked. Here is the javascript that I've started.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="item_clear.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.timer.js"></script>




</head>

<style>
h1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h3 {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h2 {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
    hr {
    clear: both;
    visibility: show;
    width: 10px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.auto-style1 {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 1px 4px;
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="layer4" class="auto-style1" style="position: absolute; width:     339px; height: 344px; z-index: 4; left: 1046px; top: 1px">    

<div>

        <div1 style="width: 327px">
<h1 style="text-align:left;float:left;">2x &nbsp;</h1>
<h1 style="text-align:right;float:left;">Cheese Burger</h1>
<!--<hr style="clear:both;"/>-->
    <h3>Lettuce</h3>
    <h3>Ketchup</h3>
    <h3>Tomato</h3>
    <h3>Pickles</h3>
    <h3>Mayo</h3>
   <h3>Mustard</h3>
</div1>  

</div>
</div>

<div id="layer3" class="auto-style1" style="position: absolute; width:     339px; height: 344px; z-index: 3; left: 699px; top: 1px">

    <div2 style="width: 327px">
<h1 style="text-align:left;float:left;">2x &nbsp;</h1>
<h1 style="text-align:right;float:left;">Cheese Burger Special</h1>
<!--<hr style="clear:both;"/>-->
    <h3>Lettuce</h3>
    <h3>Ketchup</h3>
    <h3>Tomato</h3>
    <h3>Pickles</h3>
    <h3>Mayo</h3>
    <h3>Mustard</h3>
    </div2>  

</div>

<div id="layer2" class="auto-style1" style="position: absolute; width: 339px; height: 344px; z-index: 2; left: 350px; top: 1px">

        <div3 style="width: 327px">
<h1 style="text-align:left;float:left;">2x &nbsp;</h1>
<h1 style="text-align:right;float:left;">Cheese Burger</h1>
<!--<hr style="clear:both;"/>-->
    <h3>Lettuce</h3>
    <h3>Ketchup</h3>
    <h3>Tomato</h3>
    <h3>Pickles</h3>
    <h3>Mayo</h3>
    <h3>Mustard</h3>
        </div3>  

</div>
    <div id="layer8" class="auto-style1" style="position: absolute; width: 339px; height: 344px; z-index: 8; left: 1047px; top: 349px">

<div4 style="width: 327px">
<h1 style="text-align:left;float:left;">2x &nbsp;</h1>
<h1 style="text-align:right;float:left;">Cheese Burger</h1>
<!--<hr style="clear:both;"/>-->
    <h3>Lettuce</h3>
    <h3>Ketchup</h3>
    <h3>Tomato</h3>
    <h3>Pickles</h3>
    <h3>Mayo</h3>
    <h3>Mustard</h3>
</div4>  

    </div>
    <div id="layer7" class="auto-style1" style="position: absolute; width: 339px; height: 344px; z-index: 7; left: 699px; top: 349px">

<div5 style="width: 327px">
<h1 style="text-align:left;float:left;">2x &nbsp;</h1>
<h1 style="text-align:right;float:left;">Cheese Burger</h1>
<!--<hr style="clear:both;"/>-->
    <h3>Lettuce</h3>
    <h3>Ketchup</h3>
    <h3>Tomato</h3>
    <h3>Pickles</h3>
    <h3>Mayo</h3>
    <h3>Mustard</h3>
</div5>  

    </div>
    <div id="layer6" class="auto-style1" style="position: absolute; width: 339px; height: 344px; z-index: 6; left: 350px; top: 349px">

<div6 style="width: 327px">
<h1 style="text-align:left;float:left;">2x &nbsp;</h1>
<h1 style="text-align:right;float:left;">Cheese Burger</h1>
<!--<hr style="clear:both;"/>-->
    <h3>Lettuce</h3>
    <h3>Ketchup</h3>
    <h3>Tomato</h3>
    <h3>Pickles</h3>
    <h3>Mayo</h3>
    <h3>Mustard</h3>
</div6>  

    </div>
    <div id="layer5" class="auto-style1" style="position: absolute; width: 339px; height: 344px; z-index: 5; left: 1px; top: 349px">

<div7 style="width: 327px">
<h1 style="text-align:left;float:left;">2x &nbsp;</h1>
<h1 style="text-align:right;float:left;">Cheese Burger</h1>
<!--<hr style="clear:both;"/>-->
    <h3>Lettuce</h3>
    <h3>Ketchup</h3>
    <h3>Tomato</h3>
    <h3>Pickles</h3>
    <h3>Mayo</h3>
    <h3>Mustard</h3>
 </div7>  

    </div>
    <div id="layer1" class="auto-style1" style="position: absolute; width: 339px; height: 344px; z-index: 1; left: 1px; top: 1px">

<div8 style="width: 327px">
<h1 style="text-align:left;float:left;">2x &nbsp;</h1>
<h1 style="text-align:right;float:left;">Cheese Burger</h1>
<!--<hr style="clear:both;"/>-->
    <h3>Lettuce</h3>
    <h3>Ketchup</h3>
    <h3>Tomato</h3>
    <h3>Pickles</h3>
    <h3>Mayo</h3>
    <h3>Mustard</h3>
</div8>  

    </div>

</body>
</html>




    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div").click(function(){
            $(this).empty();
        });
    });
```

How do I set it to have layer2 data go to layer 1 when layer when is emptied on click?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: This provided script is only emptying divs. This means losing the content. If you want, INSTEAD, to move some content between 4 divs, it's another story. Provide your HTML. This question looks near *unclear* to me.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/chunter1204/r3kdxs3z/

Comment: Tags like `<div1 ...>` and `<div2 ...>` are NOT valid. Use id if you want to distinguish them.

Comment: Louys Patrice Bessette - Thanks for that. I will fix it. Any comment on the original question?

Comment: Louys Patrice. When I click a box I want to empty it and have the boxes on the right shift to the left.

For example: If I click box 1 boxes 2-8 will shift to the left. Meaning box 2 data will move to box 1.

Comment: Well... It's like you gave yourself so much trouble.... You `absolutely` positionned every main `div`. If they were all relative (default), on jQuery [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/), they would move like I suppose you want. [**CHECK HERE WHERE**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/WGVBvw): I removed the absolute positionning. and added `float:left` to `auto-style1` CSS class. On remove, does it do what you want ?

Comment: Wow, Thanks. How would I keep the borders if I want the borders to stay?

Comment: ?? Where? What I did isn't empty the clicked element... I remove it. That's what makes the "shift" effect. If you want an empty square to show at the bottom right, you have to create it.

Comment: The border. I wanted to have the cells stay but the data disappear or shit to the left.

Comment: I updated the same CodePen... And I simplified your HTML and CSS.

Comment: Thanks Louys. I really appreciate your help. Ok. I have one more thing and I think I will be able to take it from here. 

Ok, How would I set it up to have more than one item in the box? For example. If I had more than one burger how would I set it up to remove them individually instead of clicking and clearing the whole box? Is the script that I used able to do this? 

Thanks.

Comment: Also. with the sourcecode that you provided, how do I get the format of 4x2?

Comment: I updated again in order to decrease the quantity and remove the `div` only when quantity is zero. I will post it as an answer with some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, it seems you gave yourself some hard times... Uselessly defining your "product" divs as position absolute with top and left dimentions, that probably took too much time to calculate.

I had to remove all this hard work in order to create the shift effect you actually want. So now, all your product divs are defined the same.

So when one of them is removed, all the others shift to the left because of `float:left`... like a waiting line.

I removed ALL your inline HTML inline CSS and used classes instead.
It's easier to maintain.

To fix the alignment problem of "Cheese Burger Special", I made these two `<h1>` behave like table cells, using CSS.

About the 4x2 grid format: Actually, the product squares need a `min-width` to show correctly. This width is the one you had calculated (339px). I applyed a `width:25%` to ensures only 4 product per line for screens wider than 1356px.

But for narrower screens (like cell phones!), the 4 per row cannot be maintained. And it's a good thing that it automatically arrange itself.

**Functions you requested**:
Now when you click on a `.product` div, it checks for the shown quantity (in `.qty`) and removes 1.
If this result is zero, it also removes the div.

The "shift effect" is done by itself because of CSS floating.

And it creates an empty div an the end of the "wainting" line, which makes the illusion that the content shifted within fixed divs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".product").click(function() {

        // Find the quantity and remove 1.
        var quantity=parseInt($(this).find(".qty").html());
        quantity--;
        $(this).find(".qty").html(quantity+"x &nbsp;");

        if(quantity==0){
            // Creates an empty square at the end of the div list.
            var temp="<div class='product'></div>";
            $(this).parent().append(temp);

            // Remove this product.
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

See the code in [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/WGVBvw).
See it [Fullscreen](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/full/WGVBvw/).